# D3.js multi-series line chart using csv file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to recreate a multi-line chart like this example: [multi-series line chart](http://bl.ocks.org/atmccann/8966400)

This is my initial data file:

```
module_category,component_category,date_repair,actual,predicted
M1,P06,2009/01,39,63
M1,P06,2009/10,3,4
M1,P06,2009/11,4,3
M1,P06,2009/12,4,2
M1,P06,2009/02,29,45
M1,P06,2009/03,29,32
M1,P06,2009/04,10,22
M1,P06,2009/05,13,15
M1,P06,2009/06,9,16
M1,P06,2009/07,7,12
M1,P06,2009/08,5,9
M1,P06,2009/09,4,5
M1,P09,2009/01,7,5
M1,P09,2009/10,3,1
M1,P09,2009/02,2,3
M1,P09,2009/03,6,2
M1,P09,2009/04,4,2
M1,P09,2009/06,1,2
M1,P09,2009/07,3,2
```

I want to plot the date on the x-axis and the values for "actual" and "predicted" on the y-axis as two separate lines, but with a sum of the values specific to each particular date. For example, the total number of "actual" and "predicted" repair values for "January 2009".

After modifying the code from the example I get this:

[current displayed chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJkRG.png)

The big red spheres (shown in the picture) are meant to represent repair values higher than a particular threshold, which is in my code. The final dataset generated before plotting is meant to look like this:

```
date_repair,Actual,Predicted    
01/01/2009,11027,13250
01/02/2009,8862,12592
01/03/2009,12696,12254
01/04/2009,10666,12014
01/05/2009,10732,11776
01/06/2009,11304,16044
01/07/2009,12880,15133
01/08/2009,11582,13481
01/09/2009,9426,8314
01/10/2009,5250,6510
01/11/2009,4075,4941
01/12/2009,2789,3519
```

I then considered using a nesting function with the keys as the dates but that doesn't display anything on the page.

```js
function datelineChart(){
   var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 60},
       width = 980 - margin.left - margin.right,
       height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

   var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y/%m").parse;

   var x = d3.time.scale()
       .range([0, width]);

   var y = d3.scale.linear()
       .range([height, 0]);

   var color = d3.scale.category10();

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(x)
       .orient("bottom");

   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(y)
       .orient("left")
       .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

   var line = d3.svg.line()
       .interpolate("basis")
       .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
       .y(function(d) { return y(d.no_repairs); });

   var svg = d3.select("#maincontent").append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
         .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
       .append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   d3.csv("data/Consolidated_result.csv", function(error, data) {
       if (error) throw error;
     
       data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.date_repair;}).sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .rollup(function(values){
          var counts = {}, keys = ['actual', 'predicted']
          keys.forEach(function(key){
              counts[key] = d3.sum(values, function(d){ return d[key]})
          })
        return counts
        })
      .entries(data);

      data.forEach(function(d){
        d.date = parseDate(d.key);
      })

      var repairs = data.map(function(d) {
        return { date: d.date, no_repairs: d.values};
      });

      console.log(repairs)


      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

      y.domain([
        d3.min(repairs, function(c) { return d3.min(c.no_repairs); }),
        d3.max(repairs, function(c) { return d3.max(c.no_repairs); })
      ]);

      var module = svg.selectAll(".module")
        .data(repairs)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "module"); 


      var path = svg.selectAll(".module").append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.no_repairs); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.date); });


      var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength(), path[0][1].getTotalLength()];

      console.log(totalLength);

      d3.select(path[0][0])
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[0] + " " + totalLength[0])
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[0])
        .transition() // Call Transition Method
            .duration(10000) // Set Duration timing (ms)
            .ease("linear") // Set Easing option
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)// Set final value of dash-offset for transition
            .each("end", function(){
                labels.transition()
                    .delay(function(d, i){ return i * 1000; })
                    .style("opacity",1);
            });


      d3.select(path[0][1])
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[1] + " " + totalLength[1])
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[1])
        .transition() // Call Transition Method
            .duration(10000) // Set Duration timing (ms)
            .ease("linear") // Set Easing option
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);// Set final value of dash-offset for transition
            .each("end", function(){
                labels.transition()
                    .delay(function(d, i){ return i * 1000; })
                    .style("opacity",1);

            }); 


      var point = module.append("g")
          .attr("class", "line-point");

          point.selectAll('circle')
                .data(function(d){ return d.values})
            .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return x(d.date)})
                .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return y(d.value)})
                .attr("r", 5)
                .style("fill", "white")
                .style("stroke", function(d) { 
                    if(d.value < 14000){
                        return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name);
                        }else{
                            return d3.select(this).attr("r",15).style("fill","red").style("stroke","red");
                        } 
                });
      var labels = module.append("text")
          .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
          .attr("class","label")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.key) + "," + y(d.values) + ")"; })
          .attr("x", 3)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("opacity", 0)
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Also using viewing the value of the "path" in the console shows an empty array. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort your data before plotting the chart.

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.date - b.date
});
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 980 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y/%m").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.no_repairs);
  });

var svg = d3.select("#maincontent").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/01",
  "actual": 39,
  "predicted": 63
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/10",
  "actual": 3,
  "predicted": 4
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/11",
  "actual": 4,
  "predicted": 3
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/12",
  "actual": 4,
  "predicted": 2
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/02",
  "actual": 29,
  "predicted": 45
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/03",
  "actual": 29,
  "predicted": 32
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/04",
  "actual": 10,
  "predicted": 22
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/05",
  "actual": 13,
  "predicted": 15
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/06",
  "actual": 9,
  "predicted": 16
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/07",
  "actual": 7,
  "predicted": 12
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/08",
  "actual": 5,
  "predicted": 9
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P06",
  "date_repair": "2009/09",
  "actual": 4,
  "predicted": 5
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P09",
  "date_repair": "2009/01",
  "actual": 7,
  "predicted": 5
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P09",
  "date_repair": "2009/10",
  "actual": 3,
  "predicted": 1
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P09",
  "date_repair": "2009/02",
  "actual": 2,
  "predicted": 3
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P09",
  "date_repair": "2009/03",
  "actual": 6,
  "predicted": 2
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P09",
  "date_repair": "2009/04",
  "actual": 4,
  "predicted": 2
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P09",
  "date_repair": "2009/06",
  "actual": 1,
  "predicted": 2
}, {
  "module_category": "M1",
  "component_category": "P09",
  "date_repair": "2009/07",
  "actual": 3,
  "predicted": 2
}];


color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "date_repair"
}));

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date_repair);
});

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.date - b.date
});
console.log(data);

var repairs = color.domain().map(function(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    values: data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        date: d.date,
        no_repairs: +d[name]
      };
    })
  };
});

console.log(repairs);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));

y.domain([
  d3.min(repairs, function(c) {
    return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
      return v.no_repairs;
    });
  }),
  d3.max(repairs, function(c) {
    return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
      return v.no_repairs;
    });
  })
]);
console.log("comment1");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Number of Repairs");
console.log("comment2");

var module = svg.selectAll(".module")
  .data(repairs)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "module");

var path = svg.selectAll(".module").append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.values);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  });

console.log("comment3");
var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength(), path[0][1].getTotalLength()];

console.log(totalLength);

d3.select(path[0][0])
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[0] + " " + totalLength[0])
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[0])
  .transition() // Call Transition Method
  .duration(10000) // Set Duration timing (ms)
  .ease("linear") // Set Easing option
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0) // Set final value of dash-offset for transition
  .each("end", function() {
    labels.transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return i * 1000;
      })
      .style("opacity", 1);
  });

console.log("comment4");

d3.select(path[0][1])
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength[1] + " " + totalLength[1])
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength[1])
  .transition() // Call Transition Method
  .duration(10000) // Set Duration timing (ms)
  .ease("linear") // Set Easing option
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0) // Set final value of dash-offset for transition
  .each("end", function() {
    labels.transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return i * 1000;
      })
      .style("opacity", 1);
  });


var point = module.append("g")
  .attr("class", "line-point");
console.log("comment5");

point.selectAll('circle')
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return x(d.date)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return y(d.no_repairs)
  })
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("stroke", function(d) {
    if (d.no_repairs < 14000) {
      return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name);
    } else {
      return d3.select(this).attr("r", 15).style("fill", "red").style("stroke", "red");
    }
  });

var labels = module.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) {
    return {
      name: d.name,
      value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
    };
  })
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.no_repairs) + ")";
  })
  .attr("x", 3)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="maincontent"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not getting the output I wanted. The graph is still just like the one i posted in the picture. The dataset before plotting should look like this:
`date_repair,Actual,Predicted 
01/01/2009,11027,13250
01/02/2009,8862,12592
01/03/2009,12696,12254
01/04/2009,10666,12014
01/05/2009,10732,11776 `

That's why I want to implement the d3.nest() function to sum the values based on the respective dates, but I am not making any head way with that.